# Dropdown filter list on a big DataTable using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Using a DataTable with 15K+ results, I am creating a dropdown filter list like in Excel & also google sheets. These filter lists show **all** possible results for each column (e.g. ID dropdown would effectively have 15K+ results), with a checkbox beside them to filter by. Very similar to this:

[image]

I'm currently creating something with select2 and ajax to load in all the column results, however this takes 2-3 seconds per filter due to the large dataset and additional filters applied to the datatable. This is only run when the column dropdown is selected, and then cached unless any filters change.

I could load all results into the DOM on page load, but that means another 3 seconds on page load, which isn't ideal. Plus the issue of having 15K+ results in the DOM doesn't sound practical.

We will have records of above 30K soon, and there are 28 different columns to filter by. I am looking for help on how to efficiently retrieve **all results**. I see that Google sheets is able to do it with large dataset, however they do not use pagination as I do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) which will definitely improve page loading times.

Regarding column filters, you would need to retrieve all possible value for each column via Ajax and then populate corresponding drop-down box for each column.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, however since there are so many records,  I have to do a select for **all** records rather than what's on the page. This is the issue of it being slow right now, as the ajax server-side processing on the data-table is fine, but I'm fetching all results for each column on the ajax filter lists.